# Format Data in a Chart Data Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm working on a project where I'm creating charts programmatically using VBA. These charts include data tables. The business requirements specify that the chart data cannot be tied to the source data, so the data is embedding in the chart itself.
[image]

I'm struggling to see how to format the numbers in the table to have two decimal places...In the example above the 0.1 needs to be 0.10 and the 1 needs to be 1.00. The chart removes any trailing zeros I add to the source data, and I see no options to format the data table number format. I don't know if there's a VBA answer to this or if I could find it by recording a macro, but I can't even figure it out manually! Any thoughts?

Comment: If you do it manually, you cannot create the table without source data *somewhere* (well _I_ couldn't find a way). The formatting of the source data carries over into the data table (for example "0.00" for your question). I would try to do that and then look in VBA at the manually created chart; that way you might see where that format is stored. Maybe at each number separately - as the source would allow that too.

Comment: The chart's data is never tied to a range. The data is stored in arrays and then passed to the chart during the build. If there is no way to manually change the number formatting, it sounds like I'm going to have to figure out how to make my array store the trailing zeros and hope that works...

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: wasn't me. And I don't see a reason either.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the [DataLabel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196984.aspx) object.

Examples from the linked MSDN:

```
With Charts(1).SeriesCollection(1)   
    .HasDataLabels = True  
    .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "##.##"  
End With
```

or

```
Worksheets(1).ChartObjects(1).Chart _ 
 .SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels(5).NumberFormat = "0.000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding datalabels to the chart doesn't actually solve the issue. Nor does formatting datalabels change the format of the data table.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this if `DataLabels` doesn't do it. The `DataTable` object has no options for formatting text or values beyond font name and size. You can achieve this kind of formatting programmatically to some degree by choosing variable types and pre-formatting the data before the chart is created, but I am unsure if you would be able to achieve this specific result.